# TFVC changeset - history of the comment on the changeset - anywhere?

Tags: tfs, version-control, tfvc, changeset

**Context**: TFS 2010

**Detail**: a changeset where the comment on the changeset has changed at least once.

**Question**: Can I see the history of the comment on the changeset somewhere?

Comment: TFS changesets are immutable. Comments on them cannot change. What is the actual issue you're trying to solve? Are you talking about *annotations*?

Comment: TFVC changesets are immutable _except_ the comments.  The comments can change.

Comment: Thanks @DanielMann: concerned with the comment only - looking to see what we would have to do to use this link to User Stories and "Work Items" (not in TFS). So if the Comment changes I can't see on the CS itself what the history of the Comment was (and adjust links to US items accordingly). Also means I can't get Changesets in descending comment change order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no history kept on the changeset. It's overwritten on the changeset record. It's a single string (`nvarchar(max)`) field in the ChangeSet record.

[image]

And if I'm reading the Warehouse schema correctly, the warehouse also keeps the `ChangeSetTitle` [in a single dimension and the data isn't duplicated for each time the comment changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/report/sql-reports/work-item-changeset-tables).